# How to schedule jobs on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, scheduling

I want Transmission starts up everyday at 20:00 and start downloading the existent torrents.

Comment: You can use Transmissions own scheduling mechanism for this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/286695/scheduled-download-by-transmission-during-nightly-hours-downloading-just-at-a

Comment: I've used transmission just as an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution:

Create a .service file under /etc/systemd/system directory

```
[Unit]
Description=some_script

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/user/scripts/some_script
```

---

Create a .timer file in the same directory as the .service file

```
[Unit]
Description=Runs some_script 5 mins after boot

[Timer]
OnBootSec=5min
Unit=some_script.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

Start and enable the .timer file

```
sudo systemctl start some_script.timer
sudo systemctl enable some_script.timer
```

I read this [wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers#Example) and [this blog](https://jason.the-graham.com/2013/03/06/how-to-use-systemd-timers/)

Comment: I'd recommend enabling the service first and reloading the systemctl daemon via: sudo systemctl daemon-reload

Answer (score 3):

Use [Systemd Timers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers). These are a `cron` alternative that is provided by systemd. The linked wikipage provides information on how to use them.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but adding a small example here is always better.

Answer (score -1):

Use cron:

```
(crontab -l;echo "0 20 * * * transmission-daemon" ) | crontab
```

Comment: Note that there is no `cron` installed by default. Arch uses systemd-timers as the default scheduling tool.